# "He" Vs "Him" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading Dracula's sequel, Dracula: The Un-dead. This sentence is taken from chapter 48.

> Thoughts of Dracula seeped into Mina's mind. God help her. What if it
>   was **he**?

I'm not sure if it's a printing error or some old-English style of writing but according to me, the "he" in this sentence should be "him". Any idea?

Comment: Both are fine. *he* is rather formal.

Comment: "What if it was he?"  is the kind of overwrought language that makes it sound like a real [bodice-ripper](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bodice-ripper.html).  But otherwise [see this](http://writingexplained.org/how-to-answer-the-phone-this-is-she-or-this-is-her)

Comment: @Andrew The [second link](http://writingexplained.org/how-to-answer-the-phone-this-is-she-or-this-is-her) made it all clear to me. Could you please write it as an answer so I can accept it. It's a great explanation and I think it'd be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the subjective form because it (he) is not an object; rather, it's a [predicative complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement)<sup>1</sup> of the copular (was).

However, the objective form (him) is the most natural way of using it in daily conversations. The subjective form (he) is just too formal and is not a suitable for casual use.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If you are not sure whether a noun is an object or a predicative complement. You can try the [passivation test](http://www.ello.uos.de/field.php/Syntax/TGPredCompl) to confirm it</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> it was **he**

is actually correct. The subjective is used after a *be-ing* verb.

Most people will understand

> it was **him**

Just as most people will use

> It is **me**

instead of the correct

> It is **I**.

Comment: Peter I don't quite get it, why is **he** correct? Let's say somebody asks, **"Who did it?"**. One should answer, **"It was me"** or **"I did it"** and not **"It was I"**.

Comment: The correct answer is "It was I", however common usage has become "It was me" which technically is incorrect, this issue comes up every now and then in ELL

Comment: Not so, I'm afraid, Peter. There is no rule of English grammar requiring a nominative form where a pronoun is complement of the verb "be". Accusative "me" is just as correct as nominative "I".